# How to differentiate two instances of same form control in .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have 2 Treeview in one form  as below.

```
left_treeview_node1  | right_treeview_node1 
left_treeview_node2  | right_treeview_node2 
left_treeview_node3  | right_treeview_node3
left_treeview_node4  | right_treeview_node4
```

here we can drag and drop left treenode on right for mapping.

now user has opened 2 instances of same form and he is dragging `left_treeview_node1` from first instance and dropping it to `right_treeview_node4` of another instance of same form.

so how to differentiate the another instance and stop supporting drag and drop from one instance to another instance.

are there different GUID for each instance of same form?

can we use Mutex to differentiate between 2 instances of same form?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Set the name property.  Also, the event parameters contain a link to the control  and use the parameter to get the control.

Comment: In the DragDrop event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx you can compare the sender.Parent to this form. If sender.Parent == this, it is the same instance of the form. Set a breakpoint on the event and look at the properties of Sender to find the form reference

Comment: You could always add `public Guid WindowId {get;} = Guid.NewGuid();` to the form and use that to tell them apart.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you pass the TreeNode as the object to drag:

```
    private void treeView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e) {
        treeView1.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
```

Then you want to write the DragEnter event handler on the second TreeView to verify that you indeed get a TreeNode and that it came from the TreeView you expected:

```
    private void treeView2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(TreeNode))) return;
        var node = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));
        if (node.TreeView == this.treeView1) {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }
```

The object identity check will not match it the node came from another form.  If you want to check that it came from the expected form instead of the expected TreeView (seems unlikely here) then write the test as `if (node.TreeView.FindForm() == this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Control.Handle property which uniquely identifies a control or a form in your case.

Comment: Be careful, because a Control's hWnd state can be recreated at runtime, causing a different `Control.Handle` property value. I suggest doing simple Object reference equality instead.

Answer (score 0):

Compare values returned by `Control.FindForm` - do not allow dropping if they are different for a dragged and target items.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just test in the drag events to see if the form is focused. If it's not then you know the rest. Or if you really want to be sure, disable/enable drag drop on the controls when the form loses/gains focus.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used the control's HASHCODE to determine the different instance of the control like below and it worked.

in tvw1.DragDrop event

`Dim draggedNode As TreeNode = Nothing
            draggedNode = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(GetType(TreeNode)), TreeNode)
            If draggedNode Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            If Not (draggedNode.TreeView.GetHashCode = tvwStagingArea.GetHashCode) Then
                'do whatever you want
                Exit Sub
            End If`